# Data frame to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

In R, I am using a for loop to iterate through a large data frame, trying to put the integer in the *i*th row, 7th column into a specific index in another matrix. The specific index corresponds to the index in the large data frame (again in the *i*th row, but the 2nd and 4th column instead). For example, say that my data frame has data_frame[1,2]=5, data_frame[1,4]=12, and data_frame[1,7]=375. I want to put 375 into my matrix in the index where the row has the name 5 and the column has name 12.

However, the problem (I think) is that when I do col_index=which(colnames(matrix)==data_frame[1,2]), it returns integer 0. The column name is technically 5, but I noticed it only works if I do col_index=which(colnames(matrix)=="5"). How can I make sure that (in my for loop) data_frame[i,2] corresponds to "5"?

data is saved as "out" My matrix that I want to put the data in is called "m"

```
m=matrix(nrow=87,ncol=87)
fips=sprintf("%03d",seq(1,173,by=2))
colnames(m)=fips
rownames(m)=fips
m[1:40,1:40]
```

Next, the condition that the 3rd column is equal to 27

```
for(i in 8:2446)
{
if(out[i,3]==27)
{
out_col=out[i,4]
out_row=out[i,2]
moves=out[i,7]
col_index=which(colnames(m)==paste(out_col))
row_index=which(rownames(m)==paste(out_row))
m[row_index,col_index]=moves
}
}
```

Sorry for the lack of formatting. It is putting numbers in the matrix, but they aren't the right numbers, and I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of complexity in your example, but it boils down to replacing values in `mat`, where the row name, column name, and new value are stored in `out`. Let's start with a reproducible example (it would have been helpful if you posted one!)

```
# Matrix to have values replaced
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(mat) <- c("1", "2", "3")
colnames(mat) <- c("4", "5", "6")
mat
#   4 5 6
# 1 0 0 0
# 2 0 0 0
# 3 0 0 0

out <- data.frame(row=c(1, 3, 3), col=c(6, 5, 4), val=c(1, 4, -1))
out
#   row col val
# 1   1   6   1
# 2   3   5   4
# 3   3   4  -1
```

Now, doing the replacement is a one-liner:

```
mat[cbind(as.character(out$row), as.character(out$col))] <- out$val
mat
#    4 5 6
# 1  0 0 1
# 2  0 0 0
# 3 -1 4 0
```

Basically, we're indexing `mat` by a 2-column matrix, where each row of the indexing matrix is a row name and column name.

In your example, you appear to be excluding the first 7 rows of `out`, as well as any row where `out[,3]` does not equal 27. You could simply subset `out` based on these requirements with something like `realout <- out[out[,3] == 27 & seq(nrow(out)) %in% 8:2446,]` and then do the replacement with `realout`.

Note that one added benefit of doing the replacement in this way is that it will be much faster than using a `for` loop through the rows of `out`.